# Esp32 string length limit

Tags: string, size, limit, toit

I found that the length of the line in app that runs on ***esp32*** is limited.
Below is an application that generates a string:

```
main :
  loop ::= 2459
  text  := ""
  stamp := "1234567890"
  loop.repeat :
    text += stamp
  print ("$text.size")
```

If ***loop ::= 2458*** everything is fine:

```
micrcx@micrcx-desktop:~/toit_apps/Hsm3/tests$ toit run test_str.toit
2021-06-02T17:03:43.237309Z: <process initiated>
24580
2021-06-02T17:03:44.575860Z: <process terminated - exit code: 0>
```

If ***loop ::= 2459***, a memory allocation error appears:

```
micrcx@micrcx-desktop:~/toit_apps/Hsm3/tests$ toit run test_str.toit
2021-06-02T17:04:03.507773Z: <process initiated>
2021-06-02T17:04:04.907154Z: <stack trace>
EXCEPTION error. 
ALLOCATION_FAILED
  0: string.+                  <sdk>/core/string.toit:274:5
  1: main.<block>              /home/micrcx/toit_apps/Hsm3/tests/test_str.toit:6:10
  2: SmallInteger_.repeat      <sdk>/core/numbers.toit:209:3
  3: main                      /home/micrcx/toit_apps/Hsm3/tests/test_str.toit:5:8
  4: __entry__.<lambda>        <sdk>/core/entry.toit:46:20
2021-06-02T17:04:04.954257Z: <process terminated - exit code: 1>
```

All these errors are of course not fatal, it's just nice to know the real numbers, for example, the maximum length of a string, list, hash maps & etc, in order to write an app that at one point will not fall because the size of the json file has exceeded the allowable number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any real size limitations on strings, lists, maps, etc.

The system just tries to allocate space for these objects, and reports an error when there isn't enough memory left. This, obviously, imposes fundamental limits on all objects: The ESP32 has at most 520K RAM, so no data structures can every exceed that size.

However, there are many more restrictions that come into play. IRAM memory, for example, has different properties than DRAM, and isn't well suited for normal data. Similarly, there is some memory that is used by the system.

For some data structures, like strings, it's also important that the memory is in a continuous region. Fragmentation can lead to cases where a bigger string just can't be allocated anymore because all free memory is in smaller holes where the string wouldn't fit.

Note, that using `+` to build up a string also means that there is always a copy of the previous string around, which doubles the space needed for the program.

Here is an example, to show that strings aren't fundamentally limited to ~25K:

```
main :
  loop ::= 4500
  stamp := "1234567890"
  text := stamp * loop
  print "$text.size"
```

The `*` operator on strings preallocates the required size, and thus doesn't need any other copy (as in the loop).

Comment: I actually have nothing against restrictions. They always exist. It's just that in this case, a situation is possible when the application works on the console, and the developer is sure that everything is ok, and then he transfers it to the chip and sees with horror that everything is falling. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using Arduino ESP32 [webserver library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/WebServer) I realized that when I try to print the HTML string that makes the webpage I get the following error, even if 520K RAM is quite a lot of RAM and I have 173K of free heap:

```
    String WEBPAGE = "lots of chars"
    Serial.println(WEBPAGE);
    Serial.printf("Free heap: %u\n", ESP.getFreeHeap());
```

I have on console

```
    E (49837) uart: uart_write_bytes(1159): buffer null
    Free heap: 173831
```

I found out the cause to be the string WEBPAGE that is too large (around 50k characters), with smaller strings the error doesn't happen.
So also the following function doesn't work and send and empty string instead and I see a white blank page on browser.

```
server.send(200, "text/html", WEBPAGE);
```

I beleive this is quite a big limitation using strings on ESP32

More details [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/5802#issuecomment-970426718).

Answer (score 0):

In my view the understanding of the device purpose is key, or design system that would not challenge memory limits as these are small i would use it to read and control IO, and leave heavy lifting like webserver to serial or cloud connected infra. if we start hitting limits we should re look at the design